# iOS5 - KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS in crash log

Tags: crash, ios5

I need your help to understand what's going on in this crash log for my app on iPhone 4S.

```
Date/Time:       2011-10-23 07:51:33.669 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xc0000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
 0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3205afbc objc_msgSend + 16
 1   UIKit                          0x31a19b68 -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:] + 412
 2   UIKit                          0x31a195d4 -[UIAnimator(Static) _advance:withTimestamp:] + 260
 3   UIKit                          0x31a194c6 -[UIAnimator(Static) _LCDHeartbeatCallback:] + 46
 4   QuartzCore                     0x3166441c CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)+ 160
 5   QuartzCore                     0x31664372 CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 54
 6   IOMobileFramebuffer            0x32c58f8c IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 76
 7   IOKit                          0x34ea188a IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 182
 8   CoreFoundation                 0x36cb9f3c __CFMachPortPerform + 356
 9   CoreFoundation                 0x36cc454c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
10  CoreFoundation                  0x36cc44ee __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
11  CoreFoundation                  0x36cc333c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
12  CoreFoundation                  0x36c464d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
13  CoreFoundation                  0x36c4639e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
14  GraphicsServices                0x32921fe6 GSEventRunModal + 150
15  UIKit                           0x318f673c UIApplicationMain + 1084
16  MyAppPro                        0x0000214a main (main.m:13)
17  MyAppPro                        0x00002108 start + 32
```

This [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2511146?start=0&tstart=0) to a discussion in Developer Forums seems to imply bad hardware!?

A little confused!

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is a dupe of many other questions that involve EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes.

Like this one:

[how to understand Crash Log of iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100306/how-to-understand-crash-log-of-iphone)

Why not step through your program and see if you can isolate where the crash is triggered?

The article you linked is talking about a Macintosh error with Safari, totally different than what you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - i will follow the other link that you mention.