# Why iPhone app crash on device, not on simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I'm developing an iPhone app that uses third party libraries (openEars in specific) and I'm experiencing an issue when running it on the device (iPhone 4 with 5.0.1). The application works fine on the simulator but always crash at the same point when running on device. This is the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: C3DCA230-EB1F-4C18-B173-320891E72311
CrashReporter Key:   ce8502e348826e9421531d69f8ca9abdf633c92b
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         OneTwoThree [29800]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/09D84DFC-DC52-43E6-AE72-EB28A73B4C22/OneTwoThree.app/OneTwoThree
Identifier:      OneTwoThree
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-02-04 16:22:42.407 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000001c
Crashed Thread:  3

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36297010 0x36296000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36297206 0x36296000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3436041c 0x342d3000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3435f11a 0x342d3000 + 573722
4   CoreFoundation                  0x342e24d6 0x342d3000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                  0x342e239e 0x342d3000 + 62366
6   GraphicsServices                0x30b66fc6 0x30b63000 + 16326
7   UIKit                           0x3776373c 0x37732000 + 202556
8   OneTwoThree                     0x000686d0 main (main.m:15)
9   OneTwoThree                     0x0001c9c4 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x362973b4 0x36296000 + 5044
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fc1e78 0x36fb5000 + 52856
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fc1b96 0x36fb5000 + 52118

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36297010 0x36296000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36297206 0x36296000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3436041c 0x342d3000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3435f154 0x342d3000 + 573780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x342e24d6 0x342d3000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                  0x342e239e 0x342d3000 + 62366
6   WebCore                         0x367b6128 0x3670e000 + 688424
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33132c16 0x33123000 + 64534
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33132ad0 0x33123000 + 64208

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   OneTwoThree                     0x0009837e ps_start_utt (pocketsphinx.c:620)
1   OneTwoThree                     0x00086626 -[ContinuousModel listeningLoopWithLanguageModelAtPath:dictionaryAtPath:languageModelIsJSGF:] (ContinuousModel.mm:858)
2   OneTwoThree                     0x00087f30 -[PocketsphinxController startVoiceRecognitionThreadAutoreleasePoolWithArray:] (PocketsphinxController.mm:181)
3   Foundation                      0x35ce2a8a 0x35cd2000 + 68234
4   Foundation                      0x35d7659a 0x35cd2000 + 673178
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33132c16 0x33123000 + 64534
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33132ad0 0x33123000 + 64208

Thread 4 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36297010 0x36296000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36297206 0x36296000 + 4614
2   AudioToolbox                    0x355ba48a 0x354fb000 + 783498
3   AudioToolbox                    0x355be0ae 0x354fb000 + 798894
4   AudioToolbox                    0x354fcaac 0x354fb000 + 6828
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33132c16 0x33123000 + 64534
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33132ad0 0x33123000 + 64208

Thread 3 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x000000a0      r3: 0x000000fc
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x2ff67a28      r7: 0x2ff679f0
    r8: 0x002b6420    r9: 0x08e80b22     r10: 0x002a18d0     r11: 0x000dbe60
    ip: 0x2ff6ae5c    sp: 0x2ff679d0      lr: 0x0008662d      pc: 0x0009837e
  cpsr: 0x40000030

Binary Images:
   0x1b000 -    0xc0fff +OneTwoThree armv7  <9abc322f81f63260ab6b4d94fb19a74d> /var/mobile/Applications/09D84DFC-DC52-43E6-AE72-EB28A73B4C22/OneTwoThree.app/OneTwoThree
  0x17f000 -   0x17ffff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  <cf2cce379dcd3a4c970e3196b908b0b6> /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
  0x1b7000 -   0x1b8fff +SubstrateLoader.dylib armv6  <30381ec9e24c3c289f447bf428bda2c1> /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib
  0x1db000 -   0x1e4fff +Activator.dylib armv6  <8a7d931c6871371e8c011cb2b9d60a4b> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
  0x1ec000 -   0x1f5fff +ColorKeyboard.dylib arm  <a7a6ac6e101d3e9db92d872208765f5b> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ColorKeyboard.dylib
  0x1fa000 -   0x1fdfff  libsubstrate.dylib armv6  <d375337d03a7324c9cfb608b7231eeea> /usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib
 0x15b8000 -  0x15c9fff +Springtomize2.dylib armv6  <d360e563a2343eb998b012885ae75f3e> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Springtomize2.dylib
 0x15d0000 -  0x15d6fff +Unrestrictor3G.dylib armv7  <97ea66943a073989a0bf6624ce4b55e9> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Unrestrictor3G.dylib
0x2fe1a000 - 0x2fe3bfff  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3063b000 - 0x308fcfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x308fd000 - 0x3093afff  IOKit armv7  <e5f727892ee034a4be04e6da608f413f> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3093d000 - 0x30942fff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <2066fe9b4ee73d1d83f5801b6d0bb432> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x30943000 - 0x30952fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <79f1564c1b23303eb3b7db67f9375228> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30a1c000 - 0x30a65fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <05711081dd883c58a844c5f9c251e8c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x30ac6000 - 0x30b17fff  CoreText armv7  <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30b1b000 - 0x30b22fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <6ca7dca9370132a2a592356bf9f2170b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x30b63000 - 0x30b6efff  GraphicsServices armv7  <4ec745ffb2e039faab4b39a30268f707> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x30b6f000 - 0x30bbafff  CoreLocation armv7  <e959d4dd596b31eeaa49c8c0156b1e12> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x30bbd000 - 0x30bc3fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <1e374857ac68370095ddbafe94f021a1> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x30c88000 - 0x30c8dfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <9072462f28af3665875b3ecaba002c00> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x30fc6000 - 0x30ffbfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <753be0ebdcb13b24b1a4adcdc94d6bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30ffc000 - 0x310d6fff  vImage armv7  <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x31133000 - 0x3118afff  CoreAudio armv7  <2e4975a2156e328585f2a478e80704fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x311a3000 - 0x3135ffff  ImageIO armv7  <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x313e5000 - 0x31405fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x31448000 - 0x31467fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <31a0ffbb18bf3a28b46fd286733e7d9f> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3146f000 - 0x314b2fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x314b3000 - 0x314fdfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <1f4cacb552533c948122cb180f4192b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x318cc000 - 0x31a15fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x31a18000 - 0x31a1cfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x31af0000 - 0x31af6fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <09f21c3e774c30b1aab1b56c2d6efbc3> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x31b0f000 - 0x31b46fff  Security armv7  <b89c9f6373f037f2a4801558f97b9a95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x31ebb000 - 0x31ec1fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <bfaf7fb16e5a3b2ea07c47b8b2f2b64e> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x31ec2000 - 0x32007fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <641fb6e558f239588a8bd05dbefff99a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3218b000 - 0x32251fff  GLEngine armv7  <0231a8c1fa3f3cfe82e83fc53c0cf5d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x3228b000 - 0x322d4fff  CoreMedia armv7  <d585cf4e0cfa34fa8beaa43b06a4bcd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3238f000 - 0x32466fff  CFNetwork armv7  <6fbc9f187eaa30009780e70288c9f289> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32467000 - 0x32478fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6bc443b0f87e338698cac9e5a96e8f8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x32a27000 - 0x32a2afff  CoreTime armv7  <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x32cfe000 - 0x32d06fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33089000 - 0x3308dfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <4511f0ec5b713636aaade7245a12553c> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x33091000 - 0x33093fff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <1ece4be587ca397b8f0494c56ed46976> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x33123000 - 0x331b0fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <1707c3cf3c5b3045af4bed38ff8420a6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x331b4000 - 0x331b8fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x334e6000 - 0x334eafff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33590000 - 0x335d5fff  GeoServices armv7  <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x335d6000 - 0x33631fff  StoreServices armv7  <1463a9f90fbd3d349544cf016e1ddd46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x33632000 - 0x33633fff  DataMigration armv7  <d067b65a904a3f438b5d9e13b208b117> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3365a000 - 0x3377efff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <24ff2747b3973aecb9c37960eba5ff4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33782000 - 0x33787fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <c3062554536438f9874c88363df7f60b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x3378a000 - 0x3378bfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <dbd1e77a4beb309d8f160d927d442467> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x337a2000 - 0x337a3fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x337a4000 - 0x337abfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <c0093954f6ee329aa6b4848215bcb8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x337ac000 - 0x337acfff  vecLib armv7  <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x337ad000 - 0x337b4fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x33819000 - 0x3381dfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3381e000 - 0x3388efff  CoreImage armv7  <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x33a30000 - 0x33a31fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x33a3f000 - 0x33a42fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x33aea000 - 0x33bb9fff  IMGSGX535GLDriver armv7  <5d2da30caa2539ffa37ba5ce9366fed8> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver
0x33bf0000 - 0x33bfafff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x33d8e000 - 0x33d8ffff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <9c8cee9652453241ac1fc99eab05c40a> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x33d9c000 - 0x33e48fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <4c0982b21ecf35aead8e0bef55d842b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x34078000 - 0x34084fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <eef915ed9b2c3433b03fd9030957b945> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3408d000 - 0x340b0fff  Bom armv7  <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x340e8000 - 0x34139fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x34166000 - 0x3418bfff  OpenCL armv7  <e1d5bfcdb59934b0923b9307c75e7457> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x34197000 - 0x341adfff  DictionaryServices armv7  <5bbab664f97932a79a1566fda3a4383e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x341bb000 - 0x341c7fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x341c8000 - 0x34297fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <cb91cd9952e7371a9659da26034c8324> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x342b6000 - 0x342b9fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <b18e0a845b1e317c8abcf6b5d06b29a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x342d3000 - 0x343eafff  CoreFoundation armv7  <de9eefc6109735369cfd8f3de9895da0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x343f2000 - 0x34436fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <9a79a2d389ba35389a30782ed01c46dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x34437000 - 0x34444fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34468000 - 0x34468fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x34480000 - 0x34495fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <97d6ebbb53ae3e0480f51771c9665613> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x345d3000 - 0x34699fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <ebbb32df194b331e9b3dc14e40f46833> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x346c4000 - 0x346c9fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <4d8b38f1cb603f0d8af78c56c485f05a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x346ca000 - 0x346cbfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x346cc000 - 0x346e5fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ad22ea5ee99a358691f9820e62c85058> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3476d000 - 0x34786fff  OpenAL armv7  <87e810d1a1e93b5b8523a4f97fdaaec5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL
0x3478a000 - 0x347a0fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x347a1000 - 0x347c4fff  PrintKit armv7  <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x348f0000 - 0x34e34fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x34e35000 - 0x34e37fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x34e76000 - 0x34f66fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ff595b1a042933249466e92433e1af6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34f67000 - 0x34f68fff  CoreSurface armv7  <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x34f69000 - 0x34fe2fff  ProofReader armv7  <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x3501d000 - 0x350edfff  WebKit armv7  <74661b1bf4613aafb827bfe0134ed92b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x350ee000 - 0x35348fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ab91ec33f2b23606bd0443163beff710> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x354fb000 - 0x356d8fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <da4f78fd20fb3b42b1a8be4f383d9c12> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x356f7000 - 0x35740fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x35c79000 - 0x35c8ffff  EAP8021X armv7  <16801802d86e3c479f3034034192faed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35c90000 - 0x35c9bfff  AccountSettings armv7  <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x35cd2000 - 0x35e50fff  Foundation armv7  <ce466f428d953caaac6641d186665809> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x35e5a000 - 0x35ea4fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x35f61000 - 0x35f67fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <f5633749a1c83058a28cd7d0b488e19f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x35f9e000 - 0x35fadfff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x35fae000 - 0x35fe7fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35fef000 - 0x35ff2fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35ff8000 - 0x35ff8fff  Accelerate armv7  <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x36029000 - 0x36046fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <1e36ab94661c372bab5a801d68c79353> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3604f000 - 0x3604ffff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x36296000 - 0x362acfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <afd3cb06e20336dca2e5a6e11d080504> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x362ad000 - 0x362b9fff  CoreVideo armv7  <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x362ba000 - 0x3633dfff  CoreMotion armv7  <f4365ff3974b3049b3f04b3f55a46ae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x363a0000 - 0x363a2fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <4ccf76f0e6cb3cd7b4e0087c2f284a1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x36522000 - 0x36562fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x36563000 - 0x3660dfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3660e000 - 0x366fcfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <6e858938edb93162ba8cf25702f08b16> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3670e000 - 0x36ec5fff  WebCore armv7  <7137e0ea008f3a3e8ae9e57f96d34d1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36f6b000 - 0x36f6bfff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x36f86000 - 0x36f9afff  PersistentConnection armv7  <81eb1b3e08cf3d7196313307ad60649d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x36fb5000 - 0x36fcbfff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <defe319d1f4d3c1c8c4f18ebd96b396a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x36feb000 - 0x370a6fff  AVFoundation armv7  <c971a925b82934f8881283aabb2992f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x371e2000 - 0x3721dfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <753daf497ca736739a30126661a522f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x3723e000 - 0x3723efff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3723f000 - 0x37288fff  AddressBook armv7  <0a858565acd03f28a1bc69a650b64a7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x372a3000 - 0x372a7fff  IOSurface armv7  <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3756f000 - 0x37579fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x375b4000 - 0x375bafff  MobileIcons armv7  <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x3767a000 - 0x37683fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <bf8d7c30f11a393a8adf4c8277e65aa3> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x37684000 - 0x37731fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x37732000 - 0x37bcbfff  UIKit armv7  <97b527cd6fba35c6bb39263e0f362223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x37bd1000 - 0x37c50fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <af4718fee01734748c42f2214ab6883d> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x37c75000 - 0x37c84fff  OpenGLES armv7  <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x37c85000 - 0x37c96fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7d49e385ee5d3e7eb08d06525abd6435> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x37c9f000 - 0x37ca2fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <3237bc9c109e3354bc4b38b957243f31> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x37ca3000 - 0x37cdffff  AppSupport armv7  <de0c2fbb95f8383db43acfb44e9c66fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x37d1c000 - 0x37d1cfff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x37d31000 - 0x37dfafff  Celestial armv7  <c18e76311fc33016be930da83050b96d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
```

I'can't figure out what is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might check out these:

[How to understand crash log of iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100306/how-to-understand-crash-log-of-iphone)


[EXC-BAD-ACCESS signal received](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received)

Comment: @jaytr0n links in  comments work like this `[link title](link_url)`. That also works answers and questions as well.

Comment: Thanks Richard, not sure what went wrong there...

Comment: @jaytr0n Ok but my crash log is more cryptic than the one you linked. I'm using OpenEars library to recognize speech. The library is successfully initialized by my Iphone, but when the iphone listen to some noise or speech, my app crash. I don't know if it's something linked to the library or to something I do in response to the listened speech. In the simulator, instead, it all works perfectly!

Comment: What about this? [OpenEars crash](http://www.politepix.com/forums/topic/exc_bad_access-on-iphone3g/)

Comment: @jaytr0n It seems that the crash described in the link is very different from mine. I don't even know at what point my application is crashing, and it's not related to the iPhone version. But, as suggested in one of the answers in the link, I have enabled OPENEARSLOGGING and saw the logs it provides and they seem all ok!

Comment: Symbolicate your crash log first

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the fact that while the simulator is case insensitive, the device is case sensitive. Googling can help you to find other Q&A related to your issue.

For example, if you have a viewController called AppViewController and a NIB file called AppView, this code works on the simulator, but not on the device:

```
AppViewController *appViewController = [[AppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"appView" bundle:nil];
```

(note appView instead of AppView)

Try to check any file access in your app.

Comment: I didn't know it, but I don't think this is my case. Thanks.

Comment: I had that problem twice, and both were by this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem but manged to solve it by
just removing all OpenEars files from X-code (not only references but files in the project folder as well ) and re-adding them again.

In my case, the problem was my application could not recognize the MDEF file in my project folder,
because my mdef file was corrupted or wrongly registered.
I got this solution from here.
[Problem during mdef reading (model definition)](http://www.politepix.com/forums/topic/problem-during-mdef-reading-model-definition/)

Comment: I had the same crash and it happened because I did not have all the settings and configuration files copied into my binary to the proper locations (mdef, noisedict and so on). Check your build phases.